# Laravel controllers / namespace via route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to access a controller name-space using the parameter in a route URL. Is something like this possible?

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'My\Name\Space\{clientId}\Controllers', 'middleware' => 'api'], function () {

    Route::get('api/v1/clients/{clientId}/test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

So

```
api/v1/clients/example/test
```

Would load the `TestController` class with namespace `My\Name\Space\example\Controllers` running method `test`

Since I am using laravel (and writing a package - so using a ServiceProvider) I would think there is *somewhere* I could hook in / override (and manipulate) the url parameter before the logic for deciding the controllers and controller methods are assigned.

I wish to do this with quite a few routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly for this it's best to start with the `RouteServiceProvider` located in the `App\Providers` namespace. You'll notice that the `routes.php` is included within a route group that defines a namespace to `App\Http\Controllers`. If you want to use a different namespace then it may be best to override this and either declare routes in the service provider or modify the wrapping group and use `routes.php`.

To get your desired result, you will need to get the `clientId` from the request object before your build the controllers. For the sake of commands that do not have a request object (`artisan route:list`) it's always best to default this as well. Note this is untested, if the `Request::route` is always returning null and defaulting, you can use `segment()` instead to get a specific url fragment.

```
**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function map(Router $router)
{
    // Attempt to get the route parameter clientId
    // or assign as Default
    $param = Request::route('clientId') ? : 'Default';

    $namespace = 'App\\' . $param;

    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api/v1/'
    ], function ($router) {
        // Ideally create a seperate apiroutes.php or something similar
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Now within your `routes.php` you wouldn't need a group, Just the bindings as you have them.

```
// The controller at namespace App\{clientId}\ will be used
Route::get('clients/{clientId}/test', 'AController@getTest');
```